# Implementing Dynamic programming Algo via threads to fasten-up

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Say i have this very common DP problem ( Dynamic programming) -

**Given a cost matrix cost[][] and a position (m, n) in cost[][], write a function that returns cost of minimum cost path to reach (m, n) from (0, 0). Each cell of the matrix represents a cost to traverse through that cell. Total cost of a path to reach (m, n) is sum of all the costs on that path (including both source and destination). You can only traverse down, right and diagonally lower cells from a given cell, i.e., from a given cell (i, j), cells (i+1, j), (i, j+1) and (i+1, j+1) can be traversed. You may assume that all costs are positive integers.**

[image]

PS: answer to this - 8

Now, After solving this question.. Following Question ran through my mind.

**Say i have 1000*1000 matrix. and O(n^2) will take some time (<1sec on intel i5 for sure).
   but can i minimize it further. say starting 6-8 threads using this algorithm and then synchronizing them back to get the answer at last ? will it be fast or even logically possible to get answer or i should throw this thought away**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, on such small problems (as you say < 1sec), parallel computing is less efficient than sequential due to protocol overhead (thread starting and synchronizing). Another problem might be, that you increase the cache miss rate because you're choosing the data you want to operate on "randomly" (not linearly) from the input. However, when it comes to larger problems, say matrices with 10 times as many entries, it sure is worth a thought (or two).

[image: Divide and conquer]

This is a possible solution. Given a 16x16 Matrix, we cut it into 4 equal squares. For each of those squares, one thread is responsible. The number in each little square indicates, after how many time units the result in that square can be calculated.

So, the total time is 33 units (whatever a unit is). Compared to the sequential solution with 64 units, it is just half of it. You can convince yourself that the runtime for any 2^k x 2^k Matrix is 2^(2k - 1) + 1.

However, this is only the first idea that came up to my mind. I hope that there is a (much) faster parallel solution in the world outside.

What's more, for the reasons I mentionned at the beginning of my answer, for all practical purposes, you would not achieve a speedup of 2 with my solution.

Comment: I'm just not sure about how to merge the results of 4 sub-squares to the final result..can you give me some explanation in detail?

Comment: yeah how you will synchronize them back 
?

Comment: @ShashankJain have you already understood how to synchronize back?

Comment: Hmm... What do you mean by synchronize back? When all threads are finished, the final result can be found in the last cell (33).

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with algorithmic improvements. There's no need to test N<sup>2</sup> solutions.

One key is the direction from which you entered a square. If you entered it by moving downward, there's no need to check the square to the right. Likewise, if you entered it by moving right, there's no need to check the path downward from there. The destination of a right-angle turn can always be reached via a diagonal move, leaving out one square and its positive weight/cost.

As far as threading goes, I can see (at least) a couple of ways of splitting things up. One would be to simply queue up requests from when you enter a square. I.e., instead of (for example) testing another square, it queues up requests to test its two or three exits. N threads process those requests, which generate more requests, continuing until all of them reach the end point.

This has the obvious disadvantage that you're likely to continue traversing some routes after serial code could abandon them because they're already longer than the shortest route you've round so far.

Another possibility would be to start two threads, one traversing forward, the other backward. In each, you find the shortest route to any given point along the diagonal, then you're left with a purely linear scan through those candidates to find the shortest sum.